# Detect end of animation (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

I would like to know how you detect the end of an animation.
Here is the animation:

```
image.animate().xBy(screenWidth-200).setDuration(5000).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to execute some action after the animation ends? If so try modifying your code like below :

```
   image.animate()
        .xBy(screenWidth-200)
        .setDuration(5000)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // Do something when animation ends
          }
        })
        .start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an `AnimatorListener`:

```
    Animator.AnimatorListener listener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    image.animate().xBy(screenWidth-200).setDuration(5000).setListener(listener).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

addListener(AnimatorListener) override method

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html